# self-store an object in python

Tags: python, class, oop, persistence, pickle

I have a class in Python.

```
class myclass:
     def bar():
         # do stuff
```

I need to implement some mechanism to store/cache part of the results of a function using some `store()/load()` functions.

I am constrained to use an external object, `somewriter` which offers an API for making objects persistant using a `read()/write()`. You can imagine this a  custom pickling library.

```
class myclass:
     def bar():
         # do stuff which costs losts of time
         self.results=baz
```

The storage part goes well, I am able to store the results

```
 def store(somewriter):
     somewriter.write(self)
```

However, loading the following way does not work. How to implement a cache mechanism for an object.

```
 def load(somewriter):
     self=somewriter.read()
```

Comment: You should probably have a class method that knows how to create an object from `somewriter`: `def from_somewriter(cls, somewriter): return cls(somewriter)` Unless you provide more info that's probably the best answer we can provide

Comment: I understand question is indeed very generic...

Comment: @ErroriSalvo Does marshal or pickle solve your problem? you should give more details, such as , why loading in the above way does not work?